# Maximum VSWR that can be tolerated?

Tags: transmission-line, reflection

I am trying to solve the [2013 paper](https://www.isro.gov.in/sites/default/files/pdf/recruitment/oldquepapers/sc/EC-2013.pdf) set by [ISRO](https://www.isro.gov.in/) for electrical engineers. I wanted to verify if my answer to Question no 14 is correct.

[image: q14]

The maximum RMS current is 20A, so maximum tolerable RMS voltage will be \$E_{max} = 20 \times Z_o = 20 \times 50 = 10^3\ \text{volts} \$, from this the power we get is also \$ 20 \times 10^3 \ \text{watts}\$.

Also total power transmitted into the load is given to us \$ P_T = (1 - |\Gamma|^2)P_i = 10 \times 10^3 \ \text{watts}\$

So we can find the reflection coefficient \$ \Gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$ thus

$$ VSWR  = \frac{1+|\Gamma|}{1-|\Gamma|} = 5.828$$

Actually I'm  not getting any answer in the options.

I am not clear if I was right in thinking  that the **incident** power

$$P_{incident} = \frac{E_{max}^2}{Z_o}$$

An alternative approach,

if I know max current flowing into the load is 20 A,

$$ 20^2Z_L = 10^4 $$

So we can find \$Z_L\$ = 25

$$\Gamma= \frac{Z_L - Z_o}{Z_L + Z_o}= \frac{25-50}{25+50} = -0.33$$

$$ VSWR  = \frac{1+|\Gamma|}{1-|\Gamma|} = (0.5)^{-1} = 2$$

I really was not truly happy with any of my approaches to this problem.

Comment: You are saying the accepted answer is D?

Comment: They have not released the answer key, so I don't know the correct answer. I just showed my attempt at it. I might be totally wrong.

Comment: Your calculation says VSWR=1, but option D is 2.5.

Comment: Omg, I can't believe I made that mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll fix it immediately

Comment: wait, is that *official* material? They're capitalizing the units incorrectly …

Comment: @MarcusMüller yep, I linked directly to their website. I think the serious engineers there must be too busy to set the papers. This is just the first stage so I forgive them for the quality of the paper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ifor and Iref constructively interferring
\begin{equation}
I_{max} = I_{for}+I_{ref} = 20a
\end{equation}
Power delivered to the load
\begin{equation}
P_{for}-P_{ref}=50I_{for}^2-50I_{ref}^2=10000w
\end{equation}
Two Equations and two unknowns, solve for Ifor and Iref interferring destructively = Imin
\begin{equation}
I_{for}=15a, I_{ref}=5a, I_{min}=I_{for}-I_{ref}=10a
\end{equation}
Calculate Imax/Imin
\begin{equation}
SWR_{max}=I_{max}/I_{min}=20/10=2:1
\end{equation}